# How to make button multiple clickable using loop in Android

Tags: android

```
String getValuesPressed(){

    for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++){
        final int j = i;

        buttonList[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(j == 0){//error occurs here
                    //do stuff
                }

            }
        });
    }

    return textOnScreen[finalI];

}
```

The line below is showing error

```
buttonList[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Error:

> can't resolve this method

Comment: what is the type of `buttonList` array ?

Answer (score 0):

just use setTag() to button and getTag() to get position of button which is clicked and do your stuff depends upon position.

```
ArrayList<Button> buttonArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setTag(i);
            buttonArrayList.add(button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = (int) view.getTag();
                    if (position == 0) {
                        //do stuff
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```